# Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, datepicker, angularjs-material

I can't include the angular-material library, to use angulars datepicker.
The error refers always to:

> Failed to instantiate module ngMaterial due to: Error:
>   [$injector:nomod]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/nomod?p0=ngMa...

and the next page gives the message:

> Module 'ngMaterial' is not available! You either misspelled the module
>   name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you
>   specify the dependencies as the second argument.

I tried to swap the order of the dependencies in the JavaScript- and HTML-file. Further, I tried multiple combinations of which modules should be loaded. A simple "bower update" didn't solve the problem either.

I would be thankful for every idea you have!

script.js

```
var onlineApp = angular.module('onlineApp', [
    'ng',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngMaterial',
    'pascalprecht.translate',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'flow', 'flow.img', 'flow.init', 'flow.provider' ]);
```

bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "angular-route": "^1.5.0",
    "angular-material": "^1.0.5",
    "angular-translate": "^2.6.1",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "^2.8.0",

    "jquery": "^1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.1.1",
    "bootstrapvalidator": "^0.5.0",
    "flow.js": "^2.9.0",
    "momentjs": "^2.5.1",
    "ng-file-upload": "^5.0.9",
    "ng-flow": "^2.6.1"
},
```

index.html

```
    <!-- build:js js/vendor.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/momentjs/min/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-flow/dist/ng-flow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/flow.js/dist/flow.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrapvalidator/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js js/site.js -->
    <script src="js/onlinereg.js"></script
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.
I had to expand the "Gruntfile.js" with the dependencies also.
Now it works like a charm.

Comment: May you share it?

Answer (score 0):

How to expand Gruntfile.js  with the dependencies